# Can't destroy or mine blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using a kindle on pocket 15.6. I cannot dig, destroy blocks or mine at all. I've deleted and reinstalled, restarted my kindle and deleted all my game data. Is this a known glitch? How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to see if the problem occurs on a different minecraft world?

Answer (score 1):

I only play the PC version, but there you can not mine within a certain radius of your world spawn point, so perhaps you should go farther out and try.

Comment: This is [tag:minecraft-pe]. They are two versions. Also, your answers are small and don't offer much help. See [answer].